# How do I check what roles my bot has? [Discord.js]

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to find if my bot has a specific role so it can do something else. For example:

```js
client.user.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'specific role');
```

My error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined
```

Comment: Its not working for me...

Comment: I am getting ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined```

Answer (score 2):

Let's start of by stating that users do not have roles, therefore you have to fetch the `guildMember`.
Fetching the guild member is easy;
First of all, you will have to fetch the guild the user is in. For example:

```js
var guild = client.guilds.cache.get('guild-id');
```

Secondly, you will have to find the user in that guild. For example:

```js
var member = guild.members.cache.get('user-id');
```

Then you will be able to move forward and fetch the roles

```js
member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'role-name');
```

The full example:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'); //Define discord.js
const client = new Discord.Client(); //Define the client

client.on('message' message => { //Event listener
    //Do something here
    var guild = client.guilds.cache.get(message.guild.id);
    var member = guild.members.cache.get(client.user.id);

    member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'role-name');
});

client.login('token'); //Login
```

Comment: I would not encourage people to use var. You're also not fetching a role, you're getting it from the cache.

Comment: @Noah if a guild is cached, it's roles are too

Comment: @Lioness100 they said the word "fetch". It's not a fetch.

Comment: @Noah Look, we haven't came to Stack Overflow to start arguments. I have posted the answer as finding roles in the cache as that's what worked for me. If it does not work for you, you are welcome to let me know and I can adjust my post.

Comment: Oh, sorry @Noah I didn't notice haha

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve the user into a GuildMember, since users don't have roles.

To do that you need a Guild class,after that you can use the [`guild.member()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member) method to convert it to a member

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('id of the guild'),
member = guild.member(client.user.id);
member.roles.cache.find(r=> r.name === 'name')
```

Another issue you might run into here is, the member constant being undefined, this can be solved by using `guild.members.fetch(id)` or enabling the Privileged Member intent in the Discord Developer Portal

Comment: I'd recommend to use [`<Guild>.me`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=me) instead.

Comment: idk why I am getting the same exact problem ```client.guilds.get is not a function```

Comment: `client.guilds` has all of its guilds saved in it's cache so to find a certain guild you could need to use: `client.guilds.cache.get('id');`

Comment: OK I DID IT I AM SO PROUD OF MYSELF

Answer (score 0):

So maybe I didnt explain my problem very well but here is what I found working for me `message.guild.me.roles.cache.find(r=> r.name === 'a role')` thanks to everyone for helping me !!!